# One word to describe "On the left" or "On the right" like in Above and Below

Tags: adjective-position

As in the title, It would be handy if there were equivalents of Above and Below for 'On the left' and 'On the right', I'm wondering why there aren't ?

Comment: Generally “ just left” and “right” suffice to convey  the same idea.

Comment: There _are_ words for 'on the left' ('usually' used postpositively) etc: sinister and dexter. I'd advise you to stick with 'on the left' etc.

Comment: Yes, why aren't there any?

Answer (score 1):

*Above, below, behind, before, aright, aleft*:
*aright, aleft* are almost exclusively literary, not found in general writing, at least not anymore.

[**Aright, aleft**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4tksAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22aleft%22%20%22aright%22&q=%22aleft%22%20%22aright%22#v=snippet&q=%22aleft%22%20%22aright%22&f=false)

> "*Aright, aleft, above, below,
>
>   Rushing ravenous to and fro,
>
>   The sharks with their cold blue wolfish eyes,
>
>   Dashed, as I passed, at the sinking prize,*
>   … (p.21)"

And

> "*The gallant ship has made the bay
>
>   Through tempest, storm and night,
>
>   'Mid foam and spray she holds her way,
>
>   With shoals aleft, aright;
>
>   Behind, before, the breakers roar,
>
>   And the boiling seas are white;*
>   … (p.47)"

(J. Briggs, *Beacon*, in "Contributions to the Pen and Pencil Club," GoogleBooks.

*See also:*

> *How swift the flood, the mead, the wood,
>
>   Aright, aleft, are gone.
>
>   The bridges thunder as they pass,
>
>   But earthlie sowne is none.*

(Gottfried August Bürger, "Lenore," From [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/earliestenglish00emergoog/earliestenglish00emergoog_djvu.txt))

Answer (score 0):

“Port” and “starboard” could work, as long as the relative positional element of their definition isn’t an issue. The terms historically describe the sides of ships and aircraft, but can be useful whenever conveying position. However, they possibly lack universal recognition you require.

Comment: Port and starboard are very specific and are used to separate the physical attributes of a craft from the orientation of the people aboard them. For example the port side of a ship is always the port side but it could be to your right if you are walking aft, in front of you if you are walking across the ship towards the port side or behind you if you are leaning on the starboard rail looking outward. Ultimately the port side of a ship could be above you if you were diving on a wreck which was lying on its starboard side. I don't think they work in the sense the OP has in mind.

Comment: Port and starboard just mean left and right, which would work just as well if not better. That's not the question, though.

Comment: @Kris Sorry, can't agree with you on that. I have a left hand but not a port hand. Similarly my car had a right side but not a starboard side (basically because all the seats face forwards). If I owned a boat and a plane they would have port and starboard sides but not me, my house, or my car.

Answer (score 0):

In **heraldry** - the art of designing coats of arms and shields - the terms for right and left are: ***dexter*** and ***sinister***, respectively.

It is important to note however, that the point of view is from the one holding the shield in front of themselves. Therefore, ***dexter*** is to the viewer's left, and ***sinister*** to the right.